# HTML file input not getting .rar file's mime type

Tags: angular, typescript

I have a file uploader in my Angular project. And I am limiting accepted files and controling them via file extensions and mime types. Everything works just fine, except .rar files not return any mime type, it's just an empty string.

**component.html:**

```
<input type="file" accept="{{validInputExtensions}}" #fileDropRef id="fileDropRef" multiple (change)="fileBrowseHandler($event.target.files)" />
```

**component.ts:**

```
validInputExtensions = ".jpg, .jpeg, .bmp, .png, .pdf, .txt, .rtf, .doc, .docx, .xls, .xlsx, .zip, .rar, .mp4, .JPG, .JPEG, .BMP, .PNG, .PDF, .TXT, .RTF, .DOC, .DOCX, .XLS, .XLSX, .ZIP, .RAR, .MP4";
validContentTypes: string[] = ["image/jpeg", "image/bmp", "image/png", "application/pdf", "text/plain", "application/rtf", "application/msword", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.wordprocessingml.document", "application/vnd.ms-excel", "application/vnd.openxmlformats-officedocument.spreadsheetml.sheet", "application/x-zip-compressed", "application/vnd.rar", "video/mp4"];
validExtensions: string[] = ["jpg", "jpeg", "bmp", "png", "pdf", "txt", "rtf", "doc", "docx", "xls", "xlsx", "zip", "rar", "mp4"];


fileBrowseHandler(files: Array<any>) {
    for (const item of files) {
        item.valid = true;
        item.error = "";

        if (item.size > 10485760) {
            item.valid = false;
            item.error = "Max file size is 10 MB.";
        }

        if (item.size == 0) {
            item.valid = false;
            item.error = "Min file size is 1 Byte.";
        }

        if (!this.validContentTypes.includes(item.type)) { // item.type returns empty string for .rar file
            item.valid = false;
            item.error = "Invalid file content.";
        }

        let ext = item.name.split('.');

        if (!this.validExtensions.includes(ext[ext.length - 1].toLowerCase())) {
            item.valid = false;
            item.error = "Invalid file extension.";
        }

        // Other stuff
    }

    this.fileDropEl.nativeElement.value = "";
}
```

I've tried other browsers as well, still same result. What am I missing here?

Comment: may be you are uploading a file that is not `rar` (corrupted) ?? try different file. For me `file.type` returns `"application/vnd.rar"` when i pick a rar file.

Comment: @bogdanoff Tried dozens of different rar files. Created new ones and tried them too. Same result.

Comment: hmm weird, Can test this on different page that doen't use angular lIke plain html + js.

Comment: Tried it too, same. https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-njlqp3?file=index.js

Comment: I am getting `Type: application/vnd.rar` in console, wtf happening lol (BTW I am using Linux).